# Cannot create the archive file in ios 6

Tags: iphone, ios6

i have created iphone application. and i took the  file and published the it in app store. But i have upgraded my xcode and changed the os to 4.3 - 6.0 . Now when im trying to archive the project , gives me this error.

> Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

I checked by my architecture & compiler . they are,
     Architecture - Standard(armv7,armv7s)
     Compiler -  LLVM GCC 4.2

What would be the problem ???

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. its a whole project. more than 10 classes. it worked perfectly with os 4.3 now its in 6. is thr any problem with architecture or compiler ??

Answer (score 4):

1. Remove armv7s from there and check
2. Check what value is in "Build Active Architectures Only" . If No, set that to Yes and try to build.